# How to traverse through Dynamic Object of Arrays in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object with arrays which is nothing but JSON reply from server which I converted into Object and now it looks like this (but lot of values into it):-

```
Object_return:{
       name:[1,25,2,24,3,78],
       age:[2,34,4,78]
      }
```

here name and age is dynamic coming from the server, so I do not know what exact  values coming there so I can not  refer it while iterating through the for loop

```
<th v-for = "item in Object_return.name">
```

and also I want to show this in a DataTable so the first row should looks like this

```
         ------------------
                  1 25
                 -------
         name     2 24
                 -------
                  3 78
     --------------------
```

second row

```
    ---------------------
                  2 34
                 -------
         age      4 78
      ------------------------
```

and so on and so forth for all the values coming from the server

Does someone have an idea how to do this

Comment: Hi, did you try something?

Comment: Yes I have tried to loop through it directly for example `v-for:"item in Object_return"` but I am not able to refer the names here because its unknown for me at the time it's coming... so it simple iterate over every item which I don't want. I want something shown above

Comment: @El_Matella so it is simple giving me results like this `[1,25,2,24,3,78] so on`

Comment: Is this the result you want? https://jsfiddle.net/El_Matella/9h153fe1/

Comment: @EL_Matella I want to separate the values also so this array consists of two value pairs for example 1  and 25. so in a row, it should show name 1 25 and in the same row but in the different line it should show 2 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [iterate over an object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object) and get the key value as the second argument.

```
<tr v-for="val, key in Object_return">
```

Here, `key` will be the name of the property.

Then, since you want to group the arrays in pairs, I suggest a computed property to massage the data into the format you want.

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    serverData: {
       name:[1,25,2,24,3,78],
       age:[2,34,4,78]
      }
  },
  computed:{
    massaged(){
      return Object.keys(this.serverData).reduce((acc, val) => {
        // split each array into pairs
        const copy = [...this.serverData[val]]
        let pairs = []
        while (copy.length > 0)
          pairs.push(copy.splice(0, 2))
        // add the paired array to the return object  
        acc[val] = pairs
        return acc
      }, {})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="val, key in massaged">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr v-for="pair in val">
            <td>{{pair[0]}}</td>
            <td>{{pair[1]}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, This is want I am trying to do, :)